# Is there anyway to have a DockerBuild file use an environment variables file?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a Docker container that will have a LARGE (about 100) number of customization settings.  I would prefer to have more flexibility than coding the defaults all into the DockerFile.  I notice that the `docker run` command supports this option:

```
--env-file value              Read in a file of environment variables (default [])
```

Is there any way to have a similar file-driven mechanism used by `docker build`?  Or is there a better way entirely?

Comment: Don't forget you can always ADD a shell script, RUN it and do anything/everything you can usually do in shell scripts ;)     Less layers is always better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Environment files are not supported for builds](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/6822).

> This has been discussed at large and very likely won't be added.
>   Introducing env in the build command creates host dependent builds.

[The `ARG` command and `--build-args` are available during builds](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/14634) but do not support a file like you require.

As [user2105103](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2105103/) suggests, you can COPY the env file in your build steps and then source it during a RUN.

```
COPY .env /.env
RUN set -uex; \
    . /.env; \
    echo $MY_ENV_VAR
```

Comment: Matt, I followed the user2105103 link above, but do not find anything similar to what you suggest.  I went through all those answers.  I accepted your answer though as it should allow me to do what I need.  However, if you could add a better link to the specific reference that would be great!

Comment: I don't have a reference for what user2105103 suggested apart from my example. The link was just to their profile rather than a specific solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a `bash` script that would dynamically build your custom `Dockerfiles` .